# Conjugating one-parameter subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow G$ be one-parameter subgroups.  Let $\mathfrak{x}_i \in T_1 G$ be the initial direction of $\gamma_i$.  Let $\delta\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow G$ be the one-parameter subgroup
$$\delta(t) = \gamma_1(1) \cdot \gamma_2(t) \cdot \gamma_1(1)^{-1},$$
and let $\mathfrak{y} \in T_1 G$ be the initial direction of $\delta$.

**Question**: what is the relationship between $\mathfrak{y}$ and the $\mathfrak{x}_i$?  The most naive guess is that $\mathfrak{y} = [\mathfrak{x}_1,\mathfrak{x}_2]$, but this is clearly false since this commutator is $0$ if the one-parameter subgroups commute.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there is no direct relation between $\mathfrak{x}_2$ and $\mathfrak{n}$, however, this is exactly how we define the Adjoint action of $G$ on $T_1G$. For $\xi\in T_1G$,  $\mathrm{Ad}_g \xi := \frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} g\exp(t\xi)g^{-1}$ which for a matrix group gives $g\xi g^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you express the one parameter subgroups via the exponential mapping, and put $g:=\exp(\mathfrak{r}_1)$, then $\delta(t)=g\exp(t\mathfrak{r}_2)g^{-1}=\exp(tAd(g)(\mathfrak{r}_2))$, where $Ad:G\to GL(\mathfrak g)$ denotes the adjoint action. So you need to compute $\mathfrak{n}=Ad(\exp(\mathfrak{r}_1))(\mathfrak{r}_2))$. Since $Ad$ is a homomorphism, this equals $\exp(ad(\mathfrak{r}_1))(\mathfrak{r}_2)$, where $ad$ is the adjoint action of $\mathfrak g$ on itself. In the matrix group $GL(\mathfrak g)$ exp is the matrix exponential. Thus you get $\mathfrak{n}=e^{ad(\mathfrak{r}_1)}(\mathfrak{r}_2)=\mathfrak{r}_2+[\mathfrak{r}_1,\mathfrak{r}_2]+\tfrac12[\mathfrak{r}_1,[\mathfrak{r}_1,\mathfrak{r}_2]]+\dots$.